How can I quickly mark the whole output in Jupyter Notebook?
I cannot quickly mark the Jupyter Notebook output cell to copy its output.
There is no right click menu to mark only the output window. And marking all with CtrlA does not work either since it marks the whole notebook.
I do not want to mark the whole output window from top to bottom with the mouse, from top left to bottom right. How can I quickly mark the main output and the error output altogether in one go in Jupyter Notebook?

Left double-click and hold the second click at the top left of the Juptyter Notebook frame of the output window. You should do this where you have the blank border that you can click to change the size of the window:

Nothing must be marked in the output window.
While holding the second click, shift the cursor to the right, over the borderof the main output window, and put it at the top left of it.
This marks the whole output window, ready to be copied:

PS: You can do this "trick" in any line of the output so that you would mark everything from the bottom to the line where you have the cursor.
